# Using find and sed to do batch find/replace using HTML tags

Tags: regex, linux, command-line-interface

I need to add a javascript tag immediately before the closing  tag on all pages on my site (both .html and .htm). I have used guidance from another question here but my command isn't working:

```
find . -name "*.htm*" -print | xargs sed -i 's/<\/head>/<script language="javascript" src="https://secure.appprovider.com.js"><\/script><script language="javascript">InitiateCall('767576styisgsjgshshskshjkshkshs');<\/script><\/head>/g'
```

I get:

```
sed: 1: "./index.html": invalid command code .
```

I assume the issue is to do with the regex and me needing to escape particular characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the pattern and replacement contains `/` (the ones after `https:`), which will confuse `sed`.

You need to escape these, but using a different delimiter for the `sed` command may make it more readable:

```
's@</head>@<script (etc.) ;</script></head>@g'
```

Additionally, some `sed` implementations (on BSD systems, like OS X) requires an argument for the `-i` flag.  You may give it an empty string by specifying `''`.

Comment: I am still getting:

sed: 1: "./index.html": invalid command code .

Comment: @Chris Ah, the `-i` flag expects an argument. Use `''` (empty string in single quotes).

Comment: @Chris Answer updated. And on a general note, I would advise against using `-i` when testing.